# Is this equality about limits True?

Tags: limits

Given that $f,g$ are two functions such that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$, does this imply that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)+g(x) = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} g(x)$ ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to interpret the equality of limits like $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a}g(x)$$ in the following manner:

1) If one of the limits exists then the other exists and both are equal.

2) If one of the limits diverges to $\infty$ (or $-\infty$) so does the other.

3) If one of the functions oscillates finitely or infinitely as $x \to a$ then so does the other function (with exactly the same set of accumulation points for the range of both functions).

We usually combine the above three statements into one and say that *functions $f$ and $g$ have the same limiting behavior as $x \to a$.*

Under this wider interpretation of equality of limits, we have the following conclusion: $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0\Rightarrow \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) + g(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)$$ So the answer to your question is a resounding **YES**!

Answer (score 1):

That's not true.
Consider for example,
$$f(x)=1, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ g(x)= (-1)^{[x]}x$$
where $[x]$ is the greatest integer function.

Comment: I understand your idea, but since $g(x)$ doesn't have limit $f(x) + g(x)$ doesn't have limit neither, so there is no contradiction. Isn't it?

Comment: @MarceloFornet, Hey but if the limit itself doen't exist how can the statement in question even make sense.

Comment: You are absolutely right. That's a counterexample.

Comment: @Parish i don't consider this  as counter-example simply because the two limits does not exist, i am interested if the two have positive infinity or negative infinity or some real number, but to alternate like $\sin$ or $(-1)^n$ that does not accepted as counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim g(x)$ exists, then it is true. We have the following equality $$f(x)+g(x)=g(x)\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)$$

And since both $\lim g(x)$ and $\lim\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exist, $\lim g(x)\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)$ also exists and, since it can't be an indeterminate form because the limit of the right part is $1$, we have
$$\lim g(x)\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)=(\lim g(x))\left(1+\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)=(\lim g(x))(1+0)=\lim g(x)$$

Combining this with the previous equality, we obtain

$$\lim f(x)+g(x)=\lim g(x)$$

---

But $\lim g(x)$ may not be defined. Take $g(x)$ to be any function for which $\lim g(x)$ is undefined, and set $f(x)=g(x)/(1+x)$.

Comment: why is $\lim f(x)= 0$ what if $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$. then $\lim f(x) \not= 0$

Comment: @Ahmad I meant "the limit exists and is finite". I fixed it so that it also works when the limit is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both $f$ and $g$ are real positive functions there are two cases where $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$. $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \infty$ or $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$. In both cases is trivial that the second equality holds. This arguments doesn't sostain if the function is negative or complex.

Comment: the two functions are not complex but they can be negative, but i don't see how it wont work if its negative.

Comment: See @Parish counterexample above.